# Linq FirstOrDefault evaluates predicate each iteration?

Tags: c#, linq, foreach, iteration

If I had a statement such as:

```
var item = Core.Collections.Items.FirstOrDefault(itm => itm.UserID == bytereader.readInt());
```

Does this code read an integer from my stream each iteration, or does it read the integer once, store it, then use its value throughout the lookup?

Comment: Why not just check it yourself?

Comment: I currently am using it in a situation where it doesn't matter if it does or doesn't. I'm just curious!

Comment: Still you could satisfy your curiousity with your own code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider this code:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        new[] { 1, 2, 3, 4 }.FirstOrDefault(j => j == Get());
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
    static int i = 5;
    static int Get()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("GET:" + i);
        return i--;
    }
```

It shows, that it will call the method the number of times it needs to meet the first element matching the condition. The output will be:

> GET:5
>
> GET:4
>
> GET:3

Comment: Yes it would call your method on each iteration.

Comment: Yes it does. However, think it over...your code looks like it will compare different ids with different integers from the stream....not each with each at all

Answer (score 2):

I don't know without checking but would expect it to read it each time.

But this is very easily remedied with the following version of your code.

```
byte val = bytereader.readInt();
var item = Core.Collections.Items.FirstOrDefault(itm => itm.UserID == val);
```

Myself, I would automatically take this approach anyway just to remove any doubt. Might be a good habit to form as there is no reason to read it for each item.

Comment: I know, I was kinda just curious and couldn't find documentation on this anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

It's actually quite obvious that the call is performed for each item - `FirstOrDefault()` takes an delegate as argument. This fact is a bit obscured by using a lambda method but in the end the method only sees a delegate that it can call for each item to check the predicate. In order to evaluate the right hand side only once some magic mechanism would have to understand and rewrite the method and (sometimes sadly) there is no real magic inside compilers and runtimes.